# Does rows in mysql explain mean that the table is not properly indexed?

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

Statemtent:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `announcements` 
WHERE `website` = 17 
    AND `visible_date` <= '2014-08-05' 
ORDER BY `visible_date` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

I want to get the first `announcement` having `visible_date` earler than 2014-08-05. Is there a better way to do it?

Now, if I have an index `(website, visible_date)` I guess MySQL can get the first row using the index without doing a table scan.

But the `rows` column in my `EXPLAIN` show 355 rows instead of 1.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Satya They're equivalent, just different syntax for the same thing.

Comment: @Satya Barmar's right, didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, having an index will improve the performance of your query BUT the `EXPLAIN` command is showing you the execution plan (as described here: [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)).

In order to get your result, MySQL first need to select the rows corresponding to your `WHERE` clause and then it will return only the first result (`LIMIT 1`).

That's the reason why the `EXPLAIN` is showing every matching results, the `LIMIT` statement is applied to the results that match your conditions.

An index is used to find a row more quickly but it wont filter the data of your table, you'll find more info about indexes here: [MySQL Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Hope that this explanation will help you to better understand the notion of index.